# How to replace text in last column?

Tags: powershell, text-editing

Is there an easy way how to convert text in last column(8) if last 3 characters of the string are "-TA" So for example if text string in last column is "AB-TA" it will convert text to "AB.NO" If the string "-TA" is not at the end of the last column (last 3 characters) then no change is made.There is no header in test file. Please see sample data below.

Thank you for any suggestion.

test.txt
Input:

```
04/02/2014,4.620,4.620,4.400,4.580,166535,0,A
04/02/2014,5.740,5.820,5.530,5.750,516280,0,AB
04/02/2014,48.950,49.190,48.060,48.690,205951,0,AB-TA
04/02/2014,62.670,62.760,62.440,62.640,514203,0,CD
04/02/2014,25.020,25.060,24.750,24.810,159602,0,CD-TA
```

test.txt
Output

```
04/02/2014,4.620,4.620,4.400,4.580,166535,0,A
04/02/2014,5.740,5.820,5.530,5.750,516280,0,AB
04/02/2014,48.950,49.190,48.060,48.690,205951,0,AB.NO
04/02/2014,62.670,62.760,62.440,62.640,514203,0,CD
04/02/2014,25.020,25.060,24.750,24.810,159602,0,CD.NO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$` regular expression anchor to match only end of line characters:

```powershell
Get-Content in.txt|
ForEach-Object {$_-replace'-TA$','.NO'}|
Set-Content out.txt
```

If you want to save results in the same file, then you have to preload entire file into memory:

```powershell
@(Get-Content test.txt)|
ForEach-Object {$_-replace'-TA$','.NO'}|
Set-Content test.txt
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to write the output into original file?

Comment: @jojo585 Yes it is possible.